# Can a 3W pot be connected to a 5W LED baton?

Tags: power, resistance, potentiometer, led-strip

Situation:

I got a LED baton and the brightness was higher than required.

I added a regular 22k pot in series to it, and achieved lower brightness, but within a few seconds, the pot was burnt. I went to an electrical store and asked him for a pot that can withstand the high power drawn. He said the max available was a 10k 3W pot. I've tried it, and it has lasted longer than the previous pot, but it heats up a lot and I'm not sure of it working long term. The metal pin for the trace heats up crazy and I can't adjust the resistance either.

I'm not sure how a 3W pot can hold up when the power that was to be drawn was 5W to the LED.

Specs: LED Baton 5W 10k 3W pot set to max resistance.

The light connects directly to the wall socket, and now I've added the pot in series.

If my calculations are right, given the series connection, the 5W baton would draw 20.8mA (V = 240AC) and since I've added the pot set at 10k, the current getting to the baton is 24.0mA.

So is the heating up because of the 3.2mA that is excess? If yes, will it reduce if I add a 1k resistor in series to the pot? And what would be the power rating of the resistor I should ask for when I get it?

Update: [image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: How is it being wired? A schematic would help.

Comment: Your numbers don't add up. The pot can only draw 24mA if it has 240V across it, and you said that the LED baton has 240V across it. When you put these in series it's not possible that they both still have 240V across them. We need to see a data sheet for the "baton",

Comment: You will need to tell us the inner details or link to model and specs and range of control you need. Some power supplies can be damaged by a triac dimmer or wont work But if a switch and ceramic heater resistor works, use that for now, except we cannot guess the values Hopefully it is DC current and not the AC side you are adjusting

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, The LED baton was meant to work for 240V AC supply. I've just added a potentiometer on the way now.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The LED baton is a Crompton 1ft 5W white LED baton. That's all I know about it. The potentiometer as stated, the only info I have is it's a 10K 3W pot. I've set it to max resistence because the LED is the dimmest it can get with the current connections.

Comment: Dimming this way disturbs the constant current DC supply to demand more current at the reduced AC from input voltage drop so the series R stresses the internal transistors and inductors more AND draws more current from your series R.  If you are willing to accept this risk of early electronic LED driver failure a power series R of could be used but I would advise against it.

Comment: This is really not the right way to do what you want.

Comment: @Hearth How else would I achieve it? Could you please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That's what I thought might happen. What else would be a better way?

Comment: I can't answer that without more information. Do you have a schematic?

Comment: Unit 2
Marrtree Business Park
Bowling Back Lane
Bradford
BD4 8QE


01274 657 088
01274 657 087
lamps@cromptonlamps.com

Comment: The lamp almost certainly has a regulated supply for the LEDs.  Unless it is designed to be dimmable, it will *not* act like a normal light bulb.  If it *is* designed to be dimmable, you need an LED-compatible dimmer circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the POT is rated for 240V AC and above. Anyway, after calculating the power dissipation  R x I² = (5/220) * (5/220) *10 000 = 5.165W, It's above the 3W of the pot.

Using this technique to reduce the output of a 240V device is not good because it must be done within the inside circuitry of the appliance, not from outside, on the AC line.
It's even possible that the inner circuit tries to regulate the current of the led to compensate for the resistance you added, increasing the consumption and power dissipation even more.
So even if you can find a 10W ceramic resistor, I would not recommend to use it.

The solution is to modify the electronic inside the appliance itself: Finding how much current the led is taking and then replacing the circuitry by a constant current supply with less current or, if you don't find one, to find out the voltage of the led diode and find an adjustable constant voltage supply.

Buying another appliance may be easier and cheaper.

Comment: what pot setting would exceet the 5W?

Comment: 10K. but the pot is 3W. So you would have to lower the resistance down to under 6K to barely not exceed the limitation. The formula is easy.

Comment: @Fredled Thank you for the response. I had calculated the same before buying the pot and asked for a 5W pot. But he said 3W was the max they had. 

I will consider a lower voltage supply option. 

Given that the pot setting leads to the voltage across the LED batten being 111V, can I use a transformer (let's say I find one that supplies this voltage) and connect the LED to it? Is that better than connecting the pot? or worse?

Comment: @Fredled Also, since it is AC, I can achieve the same with a 0.6microF capacitor. Is that a better option than a pot?

Comment: Again, I think it's a bad idea to try to monitor the appliance by modifying its 240VAC supply. If the appliance is built for 240VAC, supplying another voltage or trying to limit its input current will have unpredictable effects. If you don't know the electronic diagram inside the appliance and don;t know with certainty how it works, you can't tell what will be the effect of a pot or a capacitor or whatever you put between the 240VAC line and the appliance.

Answer (score 0):

when using a pot as a rheostat, the a important parameter is wiper current. check your POT data-sheet for the maximum wiper current.

A 5W 230V light will have at-least 21mA current at full brightness, your pot needs to withstand that.

also be sure the pot can withstand the heating (3W is plenty) and the voltage (250VAC) and has sufficient safety isolation.

It might be easier to find an electronic dimmer than finding a suitable pot.